# AUCTeX's TeX-complete-symbol with flyspell

Tags: auctex, flyspell

I'm trying to make use of the autocomplete facilities of AUCTeX using M-TAB (actually, through the equivalent binding C-M-i), but apparently, when using `flyspell-mode` alongside with `LaTeX-mode` the flyspell command `flyspell-auto-correct-word` overrides `TeX-complete-symbol`.

So, if I try the AUCTeX manual's example `\renewc`, with dictionary set to `en_US`, when pressing C-M-i, I get the following sequence:

> `\renew` -> `\renews` -> `\renew c` -> `\Rene` -> `\Corene` -> `\newcomer` -> `\crewmen` and so on

With plain `ispell` it works as expected, but I'd like to keep `flyspell` if possible.

Any suggestions to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quote here the help of the customization option `flyspell-use-meta-tab` as answer:

> `flyspell-use-meta-tab` is a variable defined in ‘flyspell.el’.
>   Its value is nil
>   Original value was t
>
> Documentation:
>   Non-nil means that flyspell uses M-TAB to correct word.
>
> You can customize this variable.

You can set that variable to nil by <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-option` <kbd>RET</kbd> `flyspell-use-meta-tab`.

Comment: I had seen this, but didn't want to loose the functionality. As it turns out, with your suggestion, the binding is then left to `ispell-complete-word`, which works well, and doesn't mess with `TeX-complete-symbol`. So, thanks!